# CUDA cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel and grid synchronization

Tags: cuda

I am trying to understand how to synchronize a grid of threads with cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel.

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cooperative-groups/

I have a very simple kernel where two threads update an array, sync and both print the array:

```
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
namespace cg = cooperative_groups;
__global__ void kernel(float *buf){
    cg::grid_group
        grid = cg::this_grid();
    if(grid.thread_rank()<2)
        buf[grid.thread_rank()] = 10+grid.thread_rank();
    assert(grid.is_valid()); // ok!
    grid.sync();
    if(grid.thread_rank()<2)
        printf("thread=%d: %g %g\n",(int)grid.thread_rank(),buf[0],buf[1]);
}
```

Instead of printing values (10,11) twice, I get:

```
thread=0: 10 0
thread=1: 0 11
```

All cuda calls were fine, cuda-memcheck is happy, my cards is "GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER" and it does support cooperative kernels work, checked with:

```
    int supportsCoopLaunch = 0;
    if( cudaSuccess != cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&supportsCoopLaunch, cudaDevAttrCooperativeLaunch, dev) )
        throw std::runtime_error("Cooperative Launch is not supported on this machine configuration.");
```

I am confused... Why I don't see the synchronization?

Comment: I explicitly mentioned cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel, this is the way how kernel is launched. Also, with <<< >>> syntax the assertion would be false.

Answer (score 1):

This test is incorrect:

```
int supportsCoopLaunch = 0;
if( cudaSuccess != cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&supportsCoopLaunch, cudaDevAttrCooperativeLaunch, dev) )
    throw std::runtime_error("Cooperative Launch is not supported on this machine configuration.");
```

The support (or lack of) is not communicated via the `cudaError_t` return value of the function, instead it is communicated via the value placed in the `supportsCoopLaunch` variable.  You would want to do something like:

```
int supportsCoopLaunch = 0;
cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&supportsCoopLaunch, cudaDevAttrCooperativeLaunch, dev); 
if( supportsCoopLaunch != 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("Cooperative Launch is not supported on this machine configuration.");
```

Comment: Cut-and-paste error, my code checks both cudaDeviceGetAttribute() call success status and supportsCoopLaunch!=0.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug. The actual code was something like that:

```
__device__ void kernel(float *buf){/* see the function body above*/}
__global__ void parent_kernel(){
  float buf[2]; // per-thread buffer!!! The kernel will not 'sync' it!
  kernel(buf);  // different kernels will get different buffers
}
```